# url_for 'static' not load js second file

Tags: javascript, flask

In my static folder there are 2 js file omn js subfolder.
Using individually:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'js/prueba.js') }}"></script>
```

or

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'js/line.js') }}"></script>
```

script are loaded.

When there are loaded at once, there are not.

File structure is:

[image]

Any idea about that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your file structure?

Comment: I just edit my question

Comment: Are you using the default `static` configuration?

Comment: not sure. How do it?

Comment: You used `static_url_path` to the Flask application initializer? This would change the default path.

Comment: No, i do not use static_url_path